# CQ-Dispatcher: How to use allowAuthorized

Tags: aem

I know I can activate caching for pages that are called by an authorized user via

```
/allowAuthorized "1"
```

in the `/cache` section.

But if a page is cached it will be delivered to everyone calling it, even to anonymous users. Can I somehow check if the user is allowed to see the content or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at (1).

You can configure a section /auth_checker that defines

- `url`: url to a script / servlet that will be called with a `HEAD` request if a valid page is requested. A page is valid, if it is in the filter section with `/type` `"allow"`
- `filter`: defines which paths should be checked and which are delivered unchecked.
- `headers`: configure additional headers here that are set in the servlet and should go to the frontend

Here is an example configuration from the Adobe online documentation:

```
/auth_checker
  {
  # request is sent to this URL with '?uri=<page>' appended
  /url "/bin/permissioncheck"

  # only the requested pages matching the filter section below are checked,
  # all other pages get delivered unchecked
  /filter
    {
    /0000
      {
      /glob "*"
      /type "deny"
      }
    /0001
      {
      /glob "/content/secure/*.html"
      /type "allow"
      }
    }
  # any header line returned from the auth_checker's HEAD request matching
  # the section below will be returned as well
  /headers
    {
    /0000
      {
      /glob "*"
      /type "deny"
      }
    /0001
      {
      /glob "Set-Cookie:*"
      /type "allow"
      }
    }
  }
```

On the page there is also a sample servlet that can be used to check the user's permissions in AEM.

(1): https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/permissions-cache.html

Comment: Cool.. just why is that not available on the main dispatcher config page..